# Not able to switch on App-notifications in dialog Notificatiobns and Actions

Tags: windows-10

I'am not able to switch on App-notifications in dialog Notificatiobns and Actions.
This option is fade out and I have also the notification in this Dialog "Some settings are managed by your organization"
I'am not logged in in a domain.

Comment: Try the solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/947755/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-while-not-on-domain?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This only works on Pro and Enterprise because they have the Group Policy editor.

1. Press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd> then type `gpedit.msc`
2. Change to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu
   and Taskbar\Notifications`
3. **Enable**, and apply 'turn off toast notifications'

Then disable it and apply.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

The registry has keys that can block access like this.

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type regedit
2. Expand the following sections: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppPrivacy\`
3. Locate and delete this, and any other notification keys: `LetAppsAccessNotifications`

This does not require a restart. There are other keys in this area that are worth reviewing.