# Windows 10 Some settings are managed by your system administrator

Tags: windows-10

I have this thing in at least Windows Update, Insider Previews are disabled and Privacy Settings where is disabled send keystrokes to Microsoft. Additionaly I have disabled Cortana "By company policy". It is my personal PC.

Please, how to fix it? Only thing that I remember that may cause it, that I tried some (public) VPNs trough Windows Network.

I have Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Just going to Settings>Privacy>Feedback - and changing data collection to basic does this. When I change it back to Enhanced, it goes away.

Comment: WOW, thanks, it worked for Insidee Builds, etc, but it didn't for Cortana...

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me, as basic / advanced was grayed-out

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue, tried several solutions I found online including the Settings>Privacy>Feedback solution to no avail. I found however that the issue was actually related to my Bitdefender Total Security... I had "Profiles" activated and this was causing the issue. Once I turned off the "Profiles" option in Bitdefender, I had full access to everything again.

I found this solution on this site [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/947755/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-while-not-on-domain). I wanted to make sure this possible solution was spread since it took me awhile to find it myself.

Comment: How about a quote?

Comment: New here, didn't know how. I made sure to link the solution.

Comment: The correct thing to do is to flag this question as a duplicate of the other one if you found the answer there working ...

Comment: @DerekCole Now you know.  So improve your answer.  You can also just delete it.