# Windows Hello on HP Spectre x360 - Couldn't Recognize You / Disabled by Administrator

Tags: windows-10, windows-hello

Brand new HP Spectre x360, running Windows 10 Enterprise Fast Ring build (16199), and I have been nuable to get Windows Hello working. Two issues:

- Upon booting I try to facial recognition login - it always says "Couldn't recognize you" no matter the lighting conditions and angle
- Shortly after being logged in when I lock the PC is says "Windows Hello is currently disabled by your administrator"

I have [tried the latest HP TrueVision FHD IR Camera driver](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Windows-Hello-not-recognizing-face/m-p/6149835#M489170). I have tried the Improve Recognition function, as well as completely removing and re-setting up. Our IT team has [pushed a Group Policy that sets "Turn on convenience PIN sign-in" to Enabled](https://superuser.com/a/1131611/32055).

When I had a Surface Pro 4 it worked flawlessly (always on Fast Ring builds), so I expected the same. Any guidance on how to troubleshoot from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with a specific Windows 10 build. It now appears to be functioning in build 16215.