# A Windows Hello Security Key has been added to my PC even though I don't have one

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, u2f

I have a Windows 10 PC linked to my Microsoft Account. For an unknown reason, most of my settings are now locked and require me to insert a security key to access them. To name a few:

- The lock screen requires either a security key or the full account password. My pin is now invalid.
- Windows defender is missing the Virus & Thread protection settings
- Windows Hello Pin is blocked
- Developer options are locked

Here's some screenshots to illustrate the above:
[image: Virus & Thread Protection]
[image: Account Protection]
[image: Sync]
[image: Sign In Options]

What I've tried to do is create a new local account. But when setting a new PIN on this account, I've been required to insert a 6 character long PIN even though I've been using a 4 character length. Therefore I think something have messed with my security settings. In addition, I changed the account type to administration but the Virus and Thread protection settings in Windows Defender are also missing.

What I also tried, is per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1334997/windows-10-hello-on-domain-joined-computer-credentials-could-not-be-verified?rq=1) (Suggested by @Ramhound), to delete the `Ngc` folder `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\NGC` and restarting the PC. Now the security key option is no longer available at sign in (a good thing), but the blocked areas in settings / Windows defender are still intact.

My laptop is a Lenovo Legion Y520 with a genuine OEM Windows 10 Home Edition (Version 1909). No new programs were installed on this PC before this happened.

Is there a way to solve this issue other than resetting this PC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104005/discussion-between-ramhound-and-ziad-akiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve this issue other than resetting this PC?
>
> [image]

Based on the fact you are unable to synchronize your settings.  I suspect the problem is due to the fact you are linked to a work or school account.

> [image]

This indicates that that is indeed the case.

> In most cases, the ‘Sync is not available for your account’ error will occur due to a problem with connected accounts in the ‘Access work or school’ settings page. As it turns out, this problem is only occurring on certain PCs and Notebooks that have connected work or school accounts before the installation of a critical Windows update.
>
> Some users have confirmed that they were able to fix this issue by removing the work or school account, restarting their computer and retrying the syncing procedure. In most cases, affected users have confirmed that the syncing feature remained functional even if they ended up re-adding the work or school account afterward.

You should disconnect the local account linked to the @edu.lt account.  **Your account being managed by an Administrator due to the fact you linked to that account.**

Source: [How to Fix ‘Sync is not Available for Your Account’ Error on Windows 10?](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-sync-is-not-available-for-your-account-error-on-windows-10/)

> In either case, you’ll be prompted to review and accept your
> organisation’s new controls over your device. Once you confirm the
> Azure Active Directory policies, your device will be connected to your
> work or school. It’ll effectively be registered as one of their
> devices, giving them complete control over its operation. You’ll be
> able to access your email, company files and Windows Store for
> Business apps once the account is linked.
>
> Linking a work or school account to Windows 10 lets you use your company’s resources without being confined to the Office 365 web apps. If you aren’t sure of the settings to use, you can refer to Microsoft’s online documentation. When you’re connecting to an Azure Active Directory, your organization’s IT administrator should be able to assist you to get your device configured with the correct policies.

**Windows 10 Home is evidently eligible to join Windows 10 Azure Active Directory domians.**

Source: [How to manage personal, work and school accounts in Windows 10](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-manage-personal-work-and-school-accounts-in-windows-10)

> In Windows 10, an Azure AD user account is called a **Work or school
> account**. It is a so called organizational account provided to you by
> your employer, school or organisation as part of their Office 365 or
> Microsoft 365 Business, Enterprise, Education or Government
> subscription.

Source: [Join Windows 10 PC to Azure AD](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105501-join-windows-10-pc-azure-ad.html)