# Allow Windows Hello on domain account

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-hello

After reading lots of posts about this problem;
Ex.: [https://superuser.com/questions/1113638/cant-enable-windows-hello-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMAIJ.png), ...

I have tried all kind of ways to set the policies ( not configured/enabled, etc).
The current settings are the same as in above topic:

[Policy image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMAIJ.png)
[Policy image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxCCP.png)
[Policy image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdOU.png)

Sadly the sign-in options are still greyed out ( on a local account this works perfectly and there are no local policies changed to this computer).

I am out of ideas, is there a setting that needs to be configured on AD level as well for it to work? We are in windows 10 1809 ( We are experiencing the same problems in 1803).

[Windows Hello screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFsot.png)

Comment: You actually have nearly all the domain group polices in a non-configured state which means they are likely by default disabled.  Those are all from the domain controller and NOT the local group editor, right?

Comment: This is indeed a specific group policy called "enable windows hello" where my computer alone is under. ( this is in case i mess up something :) )