# Windows 10 Education ver. 1703 does not allow me the option to set Spotlight as my lockscreen background

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

My settings, including gpresult which showed no applied GP settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked with [this Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-spotlight) and I'm pretty sure I didn't miss anything.

This laptop is not connected to a domain, and is a fresh/clean install.

Comment: If you specifically disable the group policy.  What happens?

Comment: Any event I suspect this applies: https://superuser.com/questions/947755/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-while-not-on-domain

Comment: http://www.intowindows.com/fix-windows-spotlight-is-missing-from-windows-10/

Comment: enable it in Gpedit.msc, reboot, disable it again and reboot. look if this fixes it

Comment: related (one probably by the OP, but with some feedback by others): https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/63u18a/windows_10_education_spotlight_disabled/, https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6awbm4/windows_10_edu_ver_1703_on_personal_laptop_does/

Comment: @Ramhound

Windows is activated, the group policy settings did nothing for me unforunately, or just further increased my inability to add spotlight. I'm using Windows Dynamic Theme from the Windows App Store right now and it works well, despite only putting a bandage over the problem. I tired those steps in the other posting, but that method no longer seems to work in version 1703.